# Write a pl sql block to fetch distinct department ids

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

Write a pl sql block to fetch distinct department ids[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyJQh.jpg)

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

That would be something like this (read comments within code).

Though, the exercise is just the opposite of what I'd expect because - normally - departments exist, but nobody works in them. With enforced referential integrity constraint, you couldn't have situation as described in the exercise. After all, that's what your homework text suggests.

```
set serveroutput on
declare
  l_dept_name  dept.dept_name%type;
begin
  -- loop through all distinct DEPT_ID values in the EMP table
  for cur_r in (select distinct e.dept_id 
                from emp e
               )
  loop
    -- starting inner BEGIN-EXCEPTION-END block so that 
    -- loop goes on in case of an error
    begin
      -- retrieve department details
      select d.dept_name
        into l_dept_name
        from dept d
        where d.dept_id = cur_r.dept_id;

      -- display department info (because SELECT returned something for CUR_R.DEPT_ID)
      dbms_output.put_line('Dept ID: ' || cur_r.dept_id || ' is ' || l_dept_name);
    
    -- handle errors (because SELECT didn't return anything for CUR_R.DEPT_ID)
    exception
      when no_data_found then
        dbms_output.put_line('Dept ID: ' || cur_r.dept_id ||': no additional info');
    end;
  end loop;
end;
/
```